# Accessing external URL resources in iText

Tags: java, itext

I'm working on a JSF 2.0 project using Mojarra, PrimeFaces and Tomcat 6.x, but in front I have an Apache HTTP server.

I created a web form where I can select PDF files which I want to merge. These files are external of my WAR in a directory under Apache HTTPD's control. I use iText 2.1.7 to merge the PDF files.

At the moment I'm accessing the files as follows:

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(new URL("file:///appli/Vignette/vcm/inst-vgninst/docroot_CDC" + file));
```

However, I want to access them by HTTP:

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(new URL("http://centos" + file));
```

- centos is the name of my server, where the webapp is deployed.
- file is a string variable look like "/folder/folder1/file.pdf"

This fails. But the url http://centos/folder/folder1/file.pdf is accessible by a normal webbrowser.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PdfReader` apparently can't work directly with URLs which point to an external resource. If you really intend to work with `URL` rather than [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), then your best bet is to use [`URL#openStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) to return an `InputStream` to the `PdfReader`. It has namely also a [constructor](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#PdfReader%28java.io.InputStream%29) for that.

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(new URL("http://centos" + file).openStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

First initialise that resource through Web Driver. Refer below code for details-

```
WebDriver ie_driver = BrowserFactory.startBrowser("ie","https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/pdf/index.pdf");
ie_driver.manage().window().maximize();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new URL("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/pdf/index.pdf").openStream());
System.out.println("This PDF has "+reader.getNumberOfPages()+" pages.");
String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
System.out.println("Page Content:\n\n"+page+"\n\n");
System.out.println("Is this document tampered: "+reader.isTampered());
System.out.println("Is this document encrypted: "+reader.isEncrypted());
```

Comment: The OP has not said anything directly about the os he's running his server on, and its name even hints in a Linux direction. Thus, what good should initializing a `WebDriver` for `"ie"` do?